# CSS - Circle with letters in the middle

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to do this

[image: User Icon]

As you can see, the icon is not centered. I want the circle to be "pulled up" a bit so it looks nice.

Here is my html (angular):

// Icon component

```
<div>
    <i><ng-content></ng-content></i>
</div>
```

// Parent Component

```
<div>
    <p>Connect with <app-initials-icon>OT</app-initials-icon> {{ contact }} </p>
</div>
```

// For Simplicity (ignoring angular, so you can ignore above if you're not familiar)

```
<div>
    <p>Connect with
       <div> // the div that the css below applies to
           <i>OT</i>
       </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
div {
    display: inline-block;

}

div i {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any idea how?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. [Check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icon-component-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: You could use [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to align it

Comment: Try: Use position: relative; top: -10px; Tha should move it up. Experiment the best value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
    display: block;

}

div i {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-style: normal;
}


i {
position: relative
}


i.one {
top:-15px;
}


i.two {
bottom:-15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Connect with
       <div> // the div that the css below applies to
           <i class="one">OT</i>
       </div>
    </p>
</div>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div>
    <p>Connect with
       <div> // the div that the css below applies to
           <i class="two">OT</i>
       </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can put `position` directly on the `i` tag and you can control it's x and y using `top, left, right, and bottom`

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `div i` css to vertically align the circle.

Full css:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;

}

div i {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```